# In a text file how can I sed multiple portions of text bordered by specific text patterns of text on Unix?

Tags: text-processing, sed, data

I use `sed -n START_LINE,FINISH_LINEp filename > newfile`
to extract a specified range of text from a text file, e.g. `sed -n 45,50p datafile > newfile`.

How can I use this to extract multiple portions of text which are always bordered by the same pattern of text? e.g. the text I want to extract always begins 39 lines down from `Subject:?????` and ends immediately before `Start Date: ??/??/??`.

Answer (score 0):

While this doesn't answer your question per se, `awk` has an elegant solution.

```
$ awk '

    # Set start variable
    /Subject/ { start=NR + 39; }

    # Disable print condition below
    /Start Date/ { start=""; next; }

    # Print while line is greater than start
    NR > start && start

' someFile.txt
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the questioner is tied to `sed`, but I think `awk` might be better anyway. FWIW I think they want multiple blocks of line, so the `/Start Date/` line should just stop printing, rather than exit.

Comment: Good catch @Sparhawk.